# How to send response from web server to iphone?

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, java-server

I am making an iphone application which has user information on a web server. When user wants to login, username and password will be sent to web server. In my case to a java servlet. Then servlet will check username and password in database and send response to iphone. I managed to send username and password using ASIHTTPRequest. But i dont know how should servlet send response back to iphone app to tell that username and password matches some user's account or not. I implemented following functions:

```
 - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
 {
[self.activity stopAnimating];
NSLog(@"Request failed: %@",[request error]);

 } 

 - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
 { 
[self.activity stopAnimating];
NSLog(@"Response %d ==> %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);

 }
```

in console out put is: Response 200 ==>

How can i send response from my java servlet to the same request which comes from iphone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[request responseString]` is what you can see in your web browser. Just response a string, "OK", "NG" for example, on your server is OK (a JSON or a XML string is even better).

Answer (score 1):

i suggest using [RESTKit](http://restkit.org)

Comment: I am new to this stuff. Infact i wanna know how it works. Logically it should work like this: request to servlet, Servlet will check if username and password matches. If yes then response to iphone app. I wanna know how will i send that response to iphone app. between servlets its easy. but between servlet and iphone app how will i send response? thanx

Comment: sure , RESTKit is good for such doings, checkout their DiscussionBoard example

Comment: RESTKit is for handling the response on the iPhone; it does very little to generate the RESTful transaction, which is what the OP appears to be asking.